# Netbeans only has partial jQuery autocompletion

Tags: jquery, netbeans, autocomplete

I just downloaded netbeans 7.1 (PHP) to develop javascript. Autocompletion is working across the javascript files in the project, and jQuery is supported - somewhat.

If I type "$.is" I get the following options:

[image: Partial jQuery autocompletion]

Note the missing "isArray", "isNumeric", etc, etc...

The javascript settings in Netbeans:
[image: Javascript settings]

Question: "What am I missing?"

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're a little confused in what is jquery-specific and simple javascript functions like isarray, isnumeric etc.

Comment: I donth think so. As shown in the screenshot I access the jQuery object $, so those methods should be autocompleted. See i.e. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/

Comment: For clearity, see https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L475 - this shows some of the exposed functions